# Wordpress - execute shortcode inside php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple problem. I'm trying to execute a shortcode inside a php block. I'm using the Allow PHP plugin to let me type them into a page in wordpress. This is what I entered:

```php
 if(!is_user_logged_in())
    echo do_shortcode("[wplb]");
```

When the condition becomes true (the user isn't logged in), the shortcode doesn't work at all.

Here's a link to the plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-login-box/

Comment: Please modify the shortcode to check if the user isn't logged in, even add an extra parameter if need be, and don't use `[php]` shortcodes...

Comment: But removing the [php] blocks effectively disables the php code. The normal php tags do not work at all.

Comment: Modify the real PHP code of the shortcode `wplb`, found somewhere in a plugin or your theme and add the check `if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;`.

Comment: Yeah, I just answered my own question before you posted. Yes, I did just that. Mainly a brain fart moment and a little confusion of how shortcodes work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I understand what happened. Wordpress doesn't allow nesting of shortcodes. In addition, I basically just called the php function as normal. I shouldn't have bothered with the shortcode for the plugin in to begin with. Hopefully others learn from my simple mistake.

```
[php] if(!is_user_logged_in())
if(function_exists('wplb_login')) wplb_login();
[/php]
```